# Getting screen pixels on mouse press

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

I would like to obtain the screen pixels at the mouse coordinates when I click anywhere on the screen (including outside my application).

As a first step, I take a screenshot as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        screenshot = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(w.winId())
```

How can I map the coordinates where I have clicked to the screenshot?

I think the next step would be to convert the screenshot to a `Pixmap` to extract the pixels but I have no idea how to connect this with the mouse press coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to capture click events *outside* any Qt window is through [`grabMouse()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grabMouse). Consider that this only works on Linux:

> **Note**: On Windows, grabMouse() only works when the mouse is inside a window owned by the process. On macOS, grabMouse() only works when the mouse is inside the frame of that widget.

Also note that grabbing mouse might be dangerous:

> **Warning**: Bugs in mouse-grabbing applications very often lock the terminal. Use this function with extreme caution, and consider using the -nograb command line option while debugging.

As soon as the widget has grabbed the mouse, it will capture *all* mouse events (including mouse wheel), no matter their position, so it's also **very** important to release it as soon as possible. Then, there is no need to map the coordinates: the `mousePressEvent` already provides global positions based on screen coordinates, and since you already took a screenshot of the whole screen area, those coordinates will match.

Finally, to get the pixel data, convert the QPixmap provided by `grabWindow`, convert it to a QImage and use [`pixelColor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixelColor).

Because of the platform limitations of grabMouse, in the following example I'm creating a transparent window that acts as a "fake" mouse grabber.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        w.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.grabButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Grab')
        layout.addWidget(self.grabButton)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Waiting')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.grabButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.grabButton.toggled.connect(self.startGrab)

        self.desktopId = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().winId()

        if sys.platform != 'linux':
            self.grabber = QtWidgets.QWidget(flags=QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.grabber.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
            self.grabber.installEventFilter(self)
        else:
            self.grabber = None

    def grabPixel(self, event):
        buttonRect = self.grabButton.rect()
        buttonRect.translate(self.grabButton.mapToGlobal(QtCore.QPoint()))
        if event.globalPos() not in buttonRect:
            screenshot = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen().grabWindow(self.desktopId).toImage()
            pixel = screenshot.pixelColor(event.globalPos())
            self.label.setText('Click on {}x{}\nRGB: {}'.format(event.globalX(), event.globalY(), pixel.name()))
        self.grabButton.toggle()

    def startGrab(self, grab):
        if grab:
            if self.grabber:
                rect = QtCore.QRect()
                for screen in QtWidgets.QApplication.screens():
                    rect |= screen.geometry()
                self.grabber.setGeometry(rect)
                self.grabber.show()
            else:
                self.grabMouse()
        else:
            self.releaseMouse()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if source == self.grabber and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.grabPixel(event)
            self.grabber.hide()
        return super().eventFilter(source, event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.grabPixel(event)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215921/discussion-on-answer-by-musicamante-getting-screen-pixels-on-mouse-press).